# java.lang.nullpointerexception in url connection

Tags: java

I am a beginner in java programming. I am trying to read response from url and insert into database. I ran my program which is posted below and it came back with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapp.JavaApplication1.parseResponseString(JavaApplication1.java:41)
    at javaapp.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:71)
```

I have been trying to solve this issue on my own through research, but I could not solve it. I was wondering if anyone can help me. If you do need any other information about my program, please just ask. Thanks in advance!

And here is the code i have written

`enter code here`  package javaapp;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JavaApplication1 
{

Map<String,String> responseMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
    static String input;

    public void getResponseFromUrl() throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/home/Home");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())) ;
       String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           if (inputLine.contains("<h1>")) 
            {
                String input = inputLine;
                input = input.substring(input.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, input.indexOf("</h1>"));   
            }
        }

    }
    public void parseResponseString(String input)
    {
        String params[]=input.split(",");

        for(String param:params)
        {
            String key= param.substring(0,param.indexOf('='));
            String value= param.substring(param.indexOf('=')+1,param.length());
            responseMap.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(param);
        }
    }
    public void insertToDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Connection conn=null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","jai","jaikiran");
        String insertQuery = " INSERT INTO value_1 (username1,username2,username3,username4,username5) "+
                             " values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        pstmt.setString(1,responseMap.get("username1"));
        pstmt.setString(2,responseMap.get("username2"));
        pstmt.setString(3,responseMap.get("username3"));
        pstmt.setString(4,responseMap.get("username4"));
        pstmt.setString(5,responseMap.get("username5"));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        JavaApplication1 application =new JavaApplication1();
        application.getResponseFromUrl();
        application.parseResponseString(input);//shows exception here
        try {
            application.insertToDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}





Thanks in advance,please helpme..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `static String input;` is `null` by default and you're passing it to the `parseResponseString()` method.

You need to assign a value to the `input` variable.

I believe you wanted the assignment to be done in the `getResponseFromUrl()` method, where you have created a new `input` variable. In order to have the `static String input;` assigned with a value, you need to refer it with the `this` keyword.

```
if (inputLine.contains("<h1>")) 
{
    String input = inputLine;
    this.input = input.substring(input.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, input.indexOf("</h1>"));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at the `getResponseFromUrl` method the String input is a new variable;
you must change the  `String input = inputLine;` to  `String input2 = inputLine;` and                 `input = input2.substring(input.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, input.indexOf("</h1>"));`

your code become :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class JavaApplication1 
{

Map<String,String> responseMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
    static String input;

    public void getResponseFromUrl() throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8084/home/Home");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())) ;
       String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        {
           if (inputLine.contains("<h1>")) 
            {
                String input2 = inputLine;
                input = input2.substring(input.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, input.indexOf("</h1>"));   
            }
        }

    }
    public void parseResponseString(String input)
    {
        String params[]=input.split(",");

        for(String param:params)
        {
            String key= param.substring(0,param.indexOf('='));
            String value= param.substring(param.indexOf('=')+1,param.length());
            responseMap.put(key, value);
            System.out.println(param);
        }
    }
    public void insertToDatabase() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Connection conn=null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","jai","jaikiran");
        String insertQuery = " INSERT INTO value_1 (username1,username2,username3,username4,username5) "+
                             " values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        pstmt.setString(1,responseMap.get("username1"));
        pstmt.setString(2,responseMap.get("username2"));
        pstmt.setString(3,responseMap.get("username3"));
        pstmt.setString(4,responseMap.get("username4"));
        pstmt.setString(5,responseMap.get("username5"));
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        JavaApplication1 application =new JavaApplication1();
        application.getResponseFromUrl();
        application.parseResponseString(input);//shows exception here
        try {
            application.insertToDatabase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here:

```
String input = inputLine;
input = input.substring(input.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, input.indexOf("</h1>"));
```

Declaring a new variable `input` in the first line prevents your code to assign the value to the private field `input` (which is what you are probably trying to do).
Besides, the first line is useless, just remove it and use directly `inputLine` in the second one:

```
input = inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("<h1>") + 4, inputLine.indexOf("</h1>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong... but you define a String input as a field of your class...
I believe that you want to use in  public void getResponseFromUrl() the String input field and not the local input!!

Why I say that... obviously you try in the public void parseResponseString(String input) to take the data in the input field but you don't have anything in there... so you get NullPointerException.

So what you need to change is in:

```
public void getResponseFromUrl() throws IOException
{
    .....
    /*String input = inputLine; -> wrong, because you want to use a field and not a local var... */
    input = inputLine; /* now you are using the class field input */
    input = input.substring...
    ...
}
```